# Can this proof be done with induction

Tags: proof-verification

For any natural number $x$, $x^2 + 5$ is not divisible by $4$

Or is proof by cases the only way to go about proving this?

Comment: It can be done by induction, most easily by starting with cases $1$ and $2$ (neither of whose squares plus $5$ are divisible by $4$), and then proceeding by induction in steps of $2$.  (That is to say, $(x+2)^2+5 = x^2+4x+4+5 = (x^2+5)+4(x+1)$.)

Comment: Do you know how to proceed after the comment of Brian, i.e. is your question answered now?

Answer (score 0):

Besides induction and "*by cases*" maybe consider a direct proof, too. If $\;4 \mid x^2 +5\,$ then $x^2$ must be odd, so $x$ itself must be odd. But then $x=2y+1\,$ so $x^2+5=4y^2+4y+6 \equiv 2 \pmod 4\,$.